# Retrieving and displaying even number

Tags: c++, arrays, function, counter

So I am trying to get my even numbers to appear and tell me the result of the user input. Not sure why my function is an error in my main when I tried to just have it output in my even function won't print. Unsure why? also curious should I lock and make my array constant? It isn't changing but might feel like I have to make it constant and lock it in case if I have to change something to check for an even number. Plus I am a beginner and barely learning about arrays.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// putting our voids first to declare be declare and run first
void fillUp(int num[], int size)
{
    //user input
    cout<<"Enter "<<size<<" and then press the ENTER/RETRUN: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cin>> num[i];
    }
}
//obtaining user input and totaling them up
int total(int num[], int size)
{
    int total = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < size;i++)
    {
        total += num[i];
    }
    return total;
}
int EvenElements(int num[], int size, int& evenCounter)
{

    for(int i = 0; i<size;i++)
    {
        if(num[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            evenCounter++;
        }
    }
    return(evenCounter);
}

//display the array in a row
void display(int num[], int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<size;i++)
        {
            cout<<num[i]<<" ";
        }
}

//main function to display the results of the user input
int main()
{
    int numOne[4], numTwo[5], numThree[6], evenCounter;
    fillUp(numOne, 4);
    fillUp(numTwo, 5);
    fillUp(numThree, 6);

    cout<<"The numbers in the array are: ";
    display(numOne, 4);
    cout<<" and the total of these numbers is "<<total(numOne, 4)
            <<endl;

    cout<<"The numbers in the array are: ";
    display(numTwo, 5);
    cout<<" and the total of these numbers is "<<total(numTwo, 5)
            <<endl;

    cout<<"The numbers in the array are: ";
    display(numThree, 6);
    cout<<" and the total of these numbers is "<<total(numThree, 6)
            <<endl;
    cout<<"This is how many evens were in the array: ";
    EvenElements(evenCounter);
}
```

Comment: Given code does not compile. `EvenElements(evenCounter);` cannot be used to call `int EvenElements(int num[], int size, int& evenCounter)` Make sure you haven't broken it while debugging.

Comment: Also nowhere in the above code do you give `evenCounter` a value. You increment it in the function `EvenElements` but nowhere is it given an initial value. It should be given an initial value of zero presumably.

Comment: Also nowhere in the above code do you print the value of `evenCounter`.

Comment: I see yeah I made the counter value to now and now it appears and shows 0 so far so good I think I should definitely use the debug feature to see if I haven't broken it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `EvenElements()` requires three arguments and you're passing only one and therefore, your code as it is will not compile. Try the following (read the comments for the last 3 lines):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// putting our voids first to declare be declare and run first
void fillUp(int num[], int size)
{
    //user input
    cout<<"Enter "<<size<<" and then press the ENTER/RETRUN: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cin>> num[i];
    }
}
//obtaining user input and totaling them up
int total(int num[], int size)
{
    int total = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < size;i++)
    {
        total += num[i];
    }
    return total;
}
int EvenElements(int num[], int size, int& evenCounter)
{

    for(int i = 0; i<size;i++)
    {
        if(num[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            evenCounter++;
        }
    }
    return(evenCounter);
}

//display the array in a row
void display(int num[], int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<size;i++)
        {
            cout<<num[i]<<" ";
        }
}

//main function to display the results of the user input
int main()
{
    int numOne[4], numTwo[5], numThree[6], evenCounter;
    fillUp(numOne, 4);
    fillUp(numTwo, 5);
    fillUp(numThree, 6);

    cout<<"The numbers in the array are: ";
    display(numOne, 4);
    cout<<" and the total of these numbers is "<<total(numOne, 4)
            <<endl;

    cout<<"The numbers in the array are: ";
    display(numTwo, 5);
    cout<<" and the total of these numbers is "<<total(numTwo, 5)
            <<endl;

    cout<<"The numbers in the array are: ";
    display(numThree, 6);
    cout<<" and the total of these numbers is "<<total(numThree, 6)
            <<endl;
    cout<<"This is how many evens were in the array: ";
    // Make sure you initialise evenCounter
    evenCounter = 0;
    // Call EventElement with the right parameters
    EvenElements(numThree, 6, evenCounter);
    // Display the result
    cout<<evenCounter<<endl;
}
```

*Note*: Consider using macros for your sizes

```cpp
#define SIZE_1 4
#define SIZE_2 5
#define SIZE_3 6
```

and then replace the hard-coded numbers with the appropriate sizes.